# Are only companies and no private programmers allowed to use VS Studio 2012 Express Desktop?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Programming is my hobby and I've just downloaded VS Studio 2012 Express Desktop.

Now I am going to register it but they want me to tell them business information

> [image]

Are only companies and no private programmers allowed to use VS Studio 2012 Express Desktop?
And what shall I type in these text fields?

Comment: Company = "None"

Comment: @Walter Did you mean my spelling or shall I type this in the TextField?

Comment: Enter it in the textbox. It's a required field, but there's no rule that it has to be a real company.

Comment: What language will you use?  Most languages have more than one editor and most editors are free.  I know NetBeans supports .NET.  Also here are some more suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310735/what-is-the-best-alternative-ide-to-visual-studio

Comment: I'm going to Program with C++ and Direct X

Comment: Microsoft has always had a thing about requiring a company name to register software since as long as I can remember.

Comment: I just filled mine out with a bunch of BS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put your home address, I don't think it is intended only for businesses, I guess is in the same stride with [Visual Studio Shell](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2007/06/09/vs_shell_eclipse/) to try and attract also the opensource community.

[From the License documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350)

> A number of free development tools are also available, including
>   Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8, Visual Studio Express 2012
>   for Web, and Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop. These
>   tools provide a subset of the functionality available in Visual Studio
>   Professional 2012 and are specific to writing applications targeting
>   these platforms. Each of these Visual Studio Express 2012 products is
>   licensed per user and subject to the use terms included with the
>   product. Visual Studio Express can be used to build production
>   applications.

So it is free, [but you are right you need to register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246592.aspx) after all.  Try to put None for the organization, and 0 for numbers of employees. Business address, fill your address or whatever address you think is relevant maybe school its your choice an privacy.

Comment: https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizard.aspx?wizid=2525f0ba-d85f-4730-bd75-e1299f83e666&lcid=1033

Comment: @Eduard: In my experience, most versions of VS Studio Express will stop working if you do not register.

Comment: @Brian I edited my answer, in my experience with Visual Studio Shell I had no problems, but you can try to register if you need to, I guess the ones that stopped working they were trials but can tell for sure.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: Perhaps Shell is different from Express.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246592.aspx : "You must register your Express Edition to receive a key to unlock the product for long-term use. "

Comment: @Brian Is different, you are right I will edit my answer. Although in the link you send it said Visual Studio 2008

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: That specific URL has only been updated for 2005 and 2008, but Microsoft's policy hasn't changed.